# Method DELETE with Spring MVC and AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have a problem with RESTfull service which should DELETE record from database. When I call function in angular with REST request i receive in FireBug error message : "NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://localhost:8080/sake/dict/technologies". The Problem is only with **DELETE** method - GET, POST work fine.

**Service in Angular**

```
(function(angular) {
'use strict';
angular.module('dictionaryService', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('dictTechnologies', [ '$resource', function($resource) {
        return $resource('http://localhost:8080/sake/dict/technologies/:id', {id: '@id' }, {
            query: {method:'GET', isArray:true},
            create: {method:'POST'},
            delete: {method:'DELETE', params: {id: '@id'}}
        });
    }]).factory('dictDocuments', [ '$resource', function($resource) {
        return $resource('http://localhost:8080/sake/dict/documents/:Id', {Id: "@Id" }, {
            query: {method:'GET', isArray:true},
            create: {method:'POST'},
            delete: {method:'DELETE'}
        });
    }]);
})(window.angular);
```

**HTML** I press the button

```
 <button ng-click="deleteBtn()" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"> Delete [x] </button>
```

**Function in Controller in Angular**

```
$scope.deleteBtn= function() {
        var z = $scope.technologies[1].id; //here is JSON of technologu which I recieved in GET response
        console.log(z);
        dictTechnologies.delete(z).$promise.then(function(z) {
            //if success
        }, function(errResoponse) {

        });
    };
```

**Controller in Java Spring MVC** to make example easier I just call System.out.println();

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/dict")
public class SlownikController {


    @Autowired
    SlTechnologiaDao slTechnologiaDao;

//GET work fine
        @RequestMapping(value = "/technologies", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody List<SlTechnologia> getAllTechnologies() {
 return slTechnologiaDao.getAllTechnologia();
        }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/technologies/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public @ResponseBody int deleteTechnology(@RequestParam("id")/* @PathParam("id")*/ Integer id) {
        System.out.println(id);
        return 1;
    }

}
```

**AplicationContext - servlet**

```
<!-- Configure to plugin JSON as request and response in method handler -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
    <bean id="jsonMessageConverter"
        class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    </bean>
```

I read many pages and everywhere the method is made the same:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/technologies/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
        public @ResponseBody int deleteTechnology(@RequestParam("id")/* @PathParam("id")*/ Integer id) {
            System.out.println(id);
            return 1;
        }
```

Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing id as path variable, but trying to get it as a request param. Change your method to

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/technologies/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
 public @ResponseBody int deleteTechnology(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        System.out.println(id);
        return 1;
 }
```

`@RequestParam` is a annotation which indicates that a method parameter should be bound to a web request parameter, while `@PathVariable` is a one which indicates that a method parameter should be bound to a URI template variable.

Comment: The same error. In console in Tomcat look like they don't receive any request frorm Angular - no any new message in console even error.

Comment: Can you please verify that you are indeed sending valid ```id```, and the URL which you compose is correct? As your GET method works fine, I assume configuration is fine, and you mapping for DELETE is also fine, so the problem might be in client making a request.

Comment: Information from network in FireBug:  HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 06 Mar 2015 20:22:10 GMT
OPTIONS /sake/dict/technologies HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Origin: http://localhost:8000
Access-Control-Request-Method: DELETE
Connection: keep-alive
**and** from console.log(z) return: 2

Comment: Can you try accessing URL (http://localhost:8080/sake/dict/technologies/1) directly via any Rest Client? Anyway you are getting 403 forbidden, which means request from a client can be reached and understood, but server refuses to take any further action. Do you have any specific security configs, headers?

Comment: I installed HTTP Resource Test and with that is work. So something wrong is with my angular client.  Hmm, maybe something with CORS policy but with GET and POST it work. in web.xml I have configuration

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

Comment: I chack variable by function isNaN(z) and it's returned false, so it is a number. I changed method in Spring to: @RequestMapping(value = "/technologies/2", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
  public @ResponseBody int deleteTechnologies()  **and** is the same error. Maby the reason is that Node.JS is on port 8000, but Tomcat on 8080.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution: [How to make Apache Tomcat accept DELETE method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853812/how-to-make-apache-tomcat-accept-delete-method)

I add to web.xml filter and DELETE work:

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
            <param-value>Accept,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization,Connection,Content-Type,Host,Origin,Referer,Token-Id,User-Agent, X-Requested-With</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
            <param-value>*</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
            <param-value>GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```