# Allow DELETE request

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets

after enabling custom configuration (src/main/resources/config.properties), 
DELETE request appeared to be blocked by Tomcat.

```
HTTP Status 403
Access to the specified resource has been forbidden.
```

How to return it back to operation?

Comment: Please show your configuration and other related details

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of [how-to-make-apache-tomcat-accept-delete-metho](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853812/how-to-make-apache-tomcat-accept-delete-method)